# User management in Single Page App + REST backend

Tags: python, rest, single-page-application, mithril.js, falcon

What is the best way to do user management in a single page JS ([Mithril](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril)) app? I want users to login to load preferences and take on a role so they gain certain permissions. I have a REST API backend written in Python ([Falcon web framework](http://falcon.readthedocs.org/)).  Having read a bit  into it, it seems to boil down to sending credentials to the backend and get a token back. But the question is how that should be done. It seems that [tokens are a better method than cookies](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/), but that has effects on the exchange of secrets/tokens.  the 'xhr.withCredentials' method seems to be cookie based for instance. JWT (json web tokens) seems like a modern, interesting option, but it's hard to find a clear explanation how it could be used with a SPA.. And once the Mithril app has a token, where should I store it and how should I use it with subsequent requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't so much about Mithril, actually the only Mithril-related area is the server communication. That is done with the `m.request` method ([docs here](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.request.html)), but you need to create an object for all server communication that requires authentication.

That object should have knowledge about the auth system and detect if a token expired, then request a new one, take proper action if things fail, etc. It's a bit of work, but the process is different for most auth systems, so there's not much to do about it, except using something that already exists.

Being a small and lean MVC framework, Mithril doesn't have any security-related features built-in, but the `m.request` method is very powerful and you should use that inside the auth communication object.

The client-side storage will be in cookies or HTML5 storage. Here's an StackExchange answer that goes into more depth: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/80767 but the point is that this isn't Mithril-related either.

Thanks for linking to the tokens vs. cookies article, it was very nice!